# Monitoring and alerting on activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic, grafana, spring-jms

Hi with activemq problems that i usually face are as under:-
1. Pushed message do not get consumed
2. As a result of point 1, queue size becomes huge
3. Messages in queue keep on retrying

So is there any open source that anyone of you have used in project to send mails when queue size goes beyond a certain threshold. Can we also send message details or store it somewhere to diagnose later why these messages were not getting consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix can be a choice: https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/activemq
If the queue size becomes huge, it will create an alert. Also, it has more variety of other alerts that can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using alerting tools.
You have to collect the metrics from ActiveMQ jmx (or Jolokia over http): https://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html and react upon it.
A good stack (free, but not open source,  if you don't need high availability) is Telegraf to collect metrics + InfluxDB to persist + Grafana to render metrics and send alerts.

For example:

- on the broker you'll find the StorePercentUsage to monitor the overall disk usage
- on a queue (=Destination) you'll find the QueueSize and the ConsumerCount.

You can easily build a rule to send an alert when the metrics are above/below a threshold.

Comment: I am using Prometheus to collect metrics of different components used in my application. For ActiveMQ, I am unable to find a way to scrape the ActiveMQ metrics in Prometheus.

Comment: I don't know Prometheus but if it can collect data over http then Jolokia http interface is easy to use. It is available out of the box from Activemq 5.8 version : https://activemq.apache.org/rest